# Hadoop is complaining for nonexistent anonymous class (NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: java, hadoop, exception, jar

Consider a simple Java file which creates a `BufferedInputStream` to copy a local file `1400-8.txt` to Hadoop HDFS and print some dots as a progress status. The example is Example 3-3 from the Hadoop book [here](http://www.hadoopbook.com/).

```
// cc FileCopyWithProgress Copies a local file to a Hadoop filesystem, and shows progress
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Progressable;

// vv FileCopyWithProgress
public class FileCopyWithProgress {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String localSrc = args[0];
    String dst = args[1];
    
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(localSrc));
    
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(dst), conf);
    OutputStream out = fs.create(new Path(dst), new Progressable() {
      public void progress() {
        System.out.print(".");
      }
    });
    
    IOUtils.copyBytes(in, out, 4096, true);
  }
}
// ^^ FileCopyWithProgress
```

I compile the code and create the JAR file with

```
hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main FileCopyWithProgress.java
jar cf FileCopyWithProgress.jar FileCopyWithProgress.class
```

The above commands generate the files `FileCopyWithProgress.class`, `FileCopyWithProgress$1.class` and `FileCopyWithProgress.jar`. Then, I try to run it

```
hadoop jar FileCopyWithProgress.jar FileCopyWithProgress 1400-8.txt hdfs://localhost:9000/user/kostas/1400-8.txt
```

But, I receive the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> FileCopyWithProgress$1

To my understanding, the `FileCopyWithProgress$1.class` is due to the anonymous callback function the program declares. But since the file exists what is the issue here? Am I running the correct sequence of commands?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue so I am just posting in case it helps someone. I had to include the class `FileCopyWithProgress$1.class` in the JAR. The correct one should be

```
jar cf FileCopyWithProgress.jar FileCopyWithProgress*.class
```

Comment: Actually, you need to make a shaded JAR

Comment: Could you explain how to do that and why it is better? Thank you.

Comment: Using Maven/Gradle rather than `java jar` is how almost all companies that use Java will package applications. Shading or making "uber jars" causes all dependencies to be packaged within the JAR at runtime.